# Vuetify Calendar. How to put in a row in the "day" view, which currently contains hours in one column?

Tags: vue.js, calendar, vuetify.js

Documentation: [Calendar Doc](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/calendars/)
Codepen: [codepen](https://codepen.io/arankar2200/pen/gOPXPRj?editable=true&editors=101)
I need a series of events in day view.

```html
 <v-calendar
            ref="calendar"
            v-model="focus"
            color="primary"
            :events="events"
            :event-color="getEventColor"
            :type="type"
            @click:event="showEvent"
            @click:more="viewDay"
            @click:date="viewDay"
            @change="updateRange"
          ></v-calendar>
```

Comment: Could you specify what exactly it is, you are trying to achieve? By row you mean an additional hour or event ?

Comment: @nonNumericalFloat I have many events with the same date, I need to put them in a row in the day view, I made changes to the codpen, see please